# jQuery validateJs stops working after the 1st Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I have the following Jquery validation code:

```
$("#formObjective").validate({
    messages:
    {
        Statement: 'Value must be provided'
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        try {
            $.post($('form#formObjective').attr('action'), $('form#formObjective').serializeArray())
                .done(function (data) {
                    updateObjectiveGrid('table#objectiveGrid');
                    $('form#formObjective').closest('div').html(data);
                })
                .fail(function (xhr, error, text) {
                    alert(text);
                });
        }
        catch (ex) {
            alert('An error occurred while saving: ' + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the HTML

```
    <div id=editor>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Objective", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form", id = "formObjective" }))
    {
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Add Objective</legend>
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)


            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, "Notes", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Notes, new { @class = "form-control" } )
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" id="save"  name="action" class="btn btn-primary btn-default">@Html.GlyphIcon("plus") Save Objective</button>
                <button type="button" id="clear" name="action" class="btn btn-warning">Clear</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }
</div>
```

Now there are 2 issues I'm facing.

1. If I place the $('').validate({}) inside the
   $(document).ready(function(){}) it just does not work i.e. regular
   submit happens. If I place it outside, it works.
2. If I replace the **<form>** dynamically (the same form
       rendered from the server and replaces the existing form), then the
       validate() simply stops working and regular postback occurs.

Comment: Your replacing the `<form>` with `id="formObjective"` in your ajax call so the one your your handling no longer exists. You need to use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) - `$('#editor').on('submit', 'form', function() { ...});`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code for fix form submission problem:

```
$("#formObjective").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }).validate({
    messages:
    {
        Statement: 'Value must be provided'
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        try {
            $.post($('form#formObjective').attr('action'), $('form#formObjective').serializeArray())
                .done(function (data) {
                    updateObjectiveGrid('table#objectiveGrid');
                    $('form#formObjective').closest('div').html(data);
                })
                .fail(function (xhr, error, text) {
                    alert(text);
                });
             return false;
        }
        catch (ex) {
            alert('An error occurred while saving: ' + ex);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: but what do you think is the reason for the cause? If there is some mistake then it should never work.

Comment: This issue comes from prevent default submits by validated forms with this new update, you need to return false from your custom submit handler like this:

$("form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        // do some stuff here
        return false;
    }
});

Comment: didn't work until I called $('').valid() after e.preventDefault() in the submit handler.